# Is there Sonar properties to add custom dictionary in the Fxcop

Tags: sonarqube

Currently i am executing Fxcop rules as part of the sonar scan. We’ve got a couple of wordings that we need to add into the custom dictionary for FxCop so that don’t get raised as FxCop violations.

I have committed CodeAnalysisDictionary.xml in the repository so that developer can changer whenever required and it is versioned.

I know we can use /dictionary: argument using fxcopcmd.exe.

Is there a way we can achieve the similar result using sonar properties.

I am using the below mentioned sonar properties.

```
sonar.fxcop.mode=

sonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0
sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=C:\\Lib***
```

Any little help here is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there has been a feature request at the sonar JIRA but the state was set to "closed" with "won't fix". https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-350

On the other hand, if you add a "CustomDictionary.xml" file to the solution root folder, this works automatically.

sample CustomDictionary.xml

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <Word>"productname"</Word>
      <Word>"companyname"</Word>
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
</Dictionary>
```